# Is there a difference between using Collections.Generic.List[Int] and Collections.Generic.List``1[Int] in PowerShell?

Tags: powershell

Question says it all. Is there a difference between `Collections.Generic.List[Int]` and ``` Collections.Generic.List``1[Int] ``` in PowerShell and if so, what are those differences?

For Example if i use ``` $list = New-Object Collections.Generic.List``1[Int] ```

What is the meaning behind the "``" and "1"?

If this Question was already asked then I apologize. I couldn't find it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

They are the same:

```
PS> [Collections.Generic.List[Int]] -eq [Collections.Generic.List``1[Int]]                                
True
```

The latter is just how the type is actually named in the .NET Standard library. Generic types all have a suffix with the backtick and the number of generic type parameters. Most languages hide this from the programmer, though. PowerShell gained those unsuffixed generic types only in a later version, so both variants still work, I guess.

Comment: Thanks for quick and presices answer!  I'll mark it when i can.